# unable to update data in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to insert user's phone number into the firebase data base based on his UID, I was following this tutorial [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjTs4lMkRM4) here is my code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_settings_update);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        progressDialoge = new ProgressDialog(UserSettingsUpdate.this);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //updating the data in the user feild
                String username = UserName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
                String phonenumber = phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(username,phonenumber);
                //getting the current user and updating the details to his/her UID
                progressDialoge.setMessage("Updating settings");
                progressDialoge.show();
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                dbr.child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);
                progressDialoge.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(UserSettingsUpdate.this, "its being updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(UserSettingsUpdate.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

all of the libraries are in order, in the tutorial a new java class is created with the variables that are required by the database, here is the java class,

```
public class UserInformation {
    public String username;
    public String PhoneNumber;

    public void UserInformation(){

    }

    public UserInformation(String username, String phoneNumber) {
        this.username = username;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is the XML code,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phonenumber"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.123" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phonenumber"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.152" />
```

on the MainActivity there is a button which starts the UpdateUserSettings Activity, the button is set to redirect correctly there's something wrong with my Java file of UserSettingsUpdate as I tried to redirect the user to this activity exactly after login and the app just crashes every time.

Comment: Which error are you getting? What is the console output?

Comment: I checked the Run tab and there seems to be no error there, everything works fine but whenever I try to access my UserSettingsUpdate feild the app just crashes @PabloAlbaladejo